# Controller classes in Entity API

Tags: entities

I'm trying to follow [this article](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/creating-own-entities-entity-api) to build my first entity using Entity API module. I'm unclear about the dependency between controller classes and include files. If it says:

```
'controller class' => 'ExampleTaskController',
```

does this mean the class has to be in a separate file named exactly as the class name (as it is in Views)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

'controller class' => 'ExampleTaskController',

> controller class: The name of the class that is used to load the
>   objects. The class has to implement the
>   DrupalEntityControllerInterface interface. Leave blank to use the
>   DrupalDefaultEntityController implementation.

Says *nothing* about where the class code actually lives in Drupal. The easiest place to put it is in the same file your declaring `hook_entity_info`. Because since it's in the same file it will be found by PHP because the class will have the same `file scope` as your hook_entity_info implementation, and likely the other hook functions needed for your entity.

In PHP there are only 3 scopes: file scope, function scope and global scope.

So how can it live outside of say `YOURMODULE.module`. You declare where this class can be found in your `YOURMODULE.info` file with the `files[]` directive.

Such as:

```
name = my custom module
package = other
files[]= EntityClassController.inc
```

Files defined by the `files[]` entries are scanned for class definitions and included automatically by Drupal in its bootstrap phase to be available as-needed by running code. So your class would live in the file location of `DRUPAL_ROOT\sites\all\modules\mymodule\EntityConroller.inc` as an example.

Alot of times to organize code better developers add subfolders, or submodules to their modules you could for instance declare the class to live in an `includes` folder in your modules folder with:

```
files[]= includes/ExampleTaskContoller.inc
```

Some hook functions such as `hook_views_api` and `hook_menu` allow you to define a file location where the `page callback` function can be found (in the case of hook_menu) or where your views implementation classes/handlers/etc may be found in the case of views.

For instance [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) allows for the following 2 keys to better organize where page callback functions live in your source code:

> "**file**": A file that will be included before the page callback is
>   called; this allows page callback functions to be in separate files.
>   The file should be relative to the implementing module's directory
>   unless otherwise specified by the "file path" option. Does not apply
>   to other callbacks (only page callback).
>
> "**file path**": The path to the directory containing the file specified
>   in "file". This defaults to the path to the module implementing the
>   hook.

Views allows 1 to define where views includes lives via [hook_views_api](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_api/7):

> **path**: (optional) If includes are stored somewhere other than within
>   the root module directory, specify its path here.
>
> **template path**: (optional) A path where the module has stored it's
>   views template files. When you have specificed this key views
>   automatically uses the template files for the views. You can use the
>   same naming conventions like for normal views template files.